# What object model should i be using for this use case

Tags: data-model

We have a site list which basically is a list with multiple sites in it.

For eg.

SiteList Name : Search Engines

1. www.google.com
2. www.bing.com
3. www.ask.com

SiteList Name : Email sites

1. www.gmail.com
2. www.hotmail.com.com
3. www.yahoomail.com

I want to be able choose multiple sitelists in my quotelineitems. I could choose many siteLists in one line item.

How to architect a data model for this kind of need?

Here is what i had in mind

**Sites List**

1. Name

**SiteDetail**

1. SiteList Master/Detail   to Site List
2. site url

**QliSitesJunction**

1. Qlineitem Lookup to Quotelineitem
2. SiteList Lookup to SiteList

Comment: perhaps you might want to share a set of options you've considered and the pros-cons as you see them of each?

Comment: @cropredy Added in the way i think should work any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two objects

1. Site (Name, URL and Record Type (Search Engine/Email Site)
2. QliSitesJunction